# Convert -1 to uint C#

Tags: c#, overriding, unchecked, uint

Converting -1 to uint will not work "((uint)(-1))" solution?

```
num10 = ((uint)(-1)) >> (0x20 - num9);
```

Error:
Constant value '-1' cannot be converted to a 'uint' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)

Comment: -1 is outside the range of an unsigned integer.

Comment: Does the error message not tell you the solution?

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
uint minus1 = unchecked((uint)-1);
uint num10 = (minus1) >> (0x20 - num9);
```

Or even better

```
uint num10 = (uint.MaxValue) >> (0x20u - num9);
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you what you need to do:

```
unchecked
{
     num10 = ((uint)(-1)) >> (0x20 - num9);
}
```

However, it may not give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

An unsigned integer can represent positive values only. It can't represent -1.

If you want to represent negative values, you'll need to use a [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness) type, like `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) context.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have something that resembles negative, unsigned numbers somewhat. They have the feature that `x + (-x) == 0`

To create a "negative" uint in c# without unchecked regions, you can instead use the equivalent `(~x) + 1` which is the same as `-x`